# How to renumber scraped array

Tags: php, arrays

I am scraping data from a html page with the following code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.atletiek.co.za/atletiek.co.za/uitslae/2016ASASASeniors/160415F012.htm';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($handle);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Prevent HTML errors from displaying
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); // get the DOM

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); // start a new xPath on our DOM Object
$preBlock = $xpath->query('//pre'); // find all pre (we only got one here)

// get the first of all the pre objects
// get the 'inner value'
// split them by newlines
$preBlockString = explode("\n",$preBlock->item(0)->nodeValue); 
$startResultBlock = false;
$i = 0;


// traverse all rows
foreach ($preBlockString as $line){
    // if we found the 'Name' marker within the last row start fetching the results
    if($startResultBlock){
        $result = explode(' ', $line);
        // kill all empty entries (originating from all the space characters)
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) if (empty($value)) unset($result[$key]);
        $results[] = $result;
        // my first idea to use list does not work because of all the space characters
        // list($results[$i]['number'], $results[$i]['name'], $results[$i]['age'], $results[$i]['team'], $results[$i]['finals'], $results[$i]['wind'], $results[$i]['points']) = explode(" ", $line);
        $i++;
    }

    // if we found the word 'Name' we set a marker for the upcoming rows
    if(trim($line) == 'Finals'){
        $startResultBlock = true;

    }

}

var_dump($results);
?>
```

The output looks like this:
`array(43) { [0]=> array(7) { [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(7) "Stephen" [4]=> string(6) "Mokoka" [16]=> string(2) "31" [17]=> string(3) "Agn" [36]=> string(8) "13:40.81" [40]=> string(1) "8" } [1]=> array(7) { [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(5) "Elroy" [4]=> string(6) "Gelant" [18]=> string(2) "30" [19]=> string(4) "Acnw" [37]=> string(8) "13:43.43" [41]=> string(1) "7" } [2]=> array(7) { [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(8) "Sibusiso" [4]=> string(5) "Nzima" [16]=> string(2) "30" [17]=> string(3) "Cga" [36]=> string(8) "13:46.73" [40]=> string(1) "6" }`

I am trying to renumber everything so that it displays like this:

`array(43) { [0]=> array(7) { [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(7) "Stephen" [4]=> string(6) "Mokoka" [5]=> string(2) "31" [6]=> string(3) "Agn" [7]=> string(8) "13:40.81" [8]=> string(1) "8" } [1]=> array(7) { [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(5) "Elroy" [4]=> string(6) "Gelant" [5]=> string(2) "30" [6]=> string(4) "Acnw" [7]=> string(8) "13:43.43" [8]=> string(1) "7" } [2]=> array(7) { [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(8) "Sibusiso" [4]=> string(5) "Nzima" [5]=> string(2) "30" [6]=> string(3) "Cga" [7]=> string(8) "13:46.73" [8]=> string(1) "6" }`

I have tried various things but it keeps kicking the data out like in example 1. Does anyone have any ideas how I can renumber this please? Alternatively if it can go from 0/1 and assigns a new number, in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://www.atletiek.co.za/atletiek.co.za/uitslae/2016ASASASeniors/160415F012.htm';
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $html = curl_exec($handle);
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Prevent HTML errors from displaying
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html); // get the DOM

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); // start a new xPath on our DOM Object
  $preBlock = $xpath->query('//pre'); // find all pre (we only got one here)

// get the first of all the pre objects
// get the 'inner value'
// split them by newlines
  $preBlockString = explode("\n",$preBlock->item(0)->nodeValue);
  $startResultBlock = false;
  $i = 0;


// traverse all rows
  foreach ($preBlockString as $line){
    // if we found the 'Name' marker within the last row start fetching the results
    if($startResultBlock){
      $result = explode(' ', $line);
      // kill all empty entries (originating from all the space characters)
      foreach ($result as $key => $value) if (empty($value)) unset($result[$key]);
      $results[] = $result;
      // my first idea to use list does not work because of all the space characters
      // list($results[$i]['number'], $results[$i]['name'], $results[$i]['age'], $results[$i]['team'], $results[$i]['finals'], $results[$i]['wind'], $results[$i]['points']) = explode(" ", $line);
      $i++;
    }

    // if we found the word 'Name' we set a marker for the upcoming rows
    if(trim($line) == 'Finals'){
      $startResultBlock = true;

    }

  }

  /* This will reorder your array */
  $newResult = [];
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
    $result = array_values($result);
    array_unshift($result, '');
    unset($result[0]);
    $newResult[] = $result;
  }
  $results = $newResult;
  var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Works a charm, renumbers perfectly